# Index & Match formula does not show the repeated entry with different value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have an [excel spreadsheet - downloadable here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=53364233111112661814) contains some columns as following :

```
Column A : Companies' Names
Column B : Project's Name
```

When I try to filter my data using combo box to show only companies in specific area and use `INDEX` and `MATCH` to show all the related data in same row with the company name in the search result, since I have some companies has more than project, unlikely `INDEX` and `MATCH` just repeat first row for the company name only like the following:

```
Company1    Project 1
Company1    Project 1
```

Although company 1 has two projects 1 and 2 and must be as following

```
Company1   Project1
Company1   Project2
```

But the formula just keep repeating first row it finds.

Pic 1 - the search result which is incorrect

[image]

Pic 2 - the main data which I want to appear like this in the search result

[image]

Comment: unless you have clear example, you will not be able to get a feedback from the community. Please give a proper example with screenshot of your data, example and what you expect.

Comment: please find the attached print screen, pic 1 shows the search result which is not correct , pic 2 shows the main data which has to be in the search result http://s14.postimg.org/g0jpiou9t/image.png    -   http://s21.postimg.org/9ehavbx5z/image.png

Comment: could you give an English example or translate the columns, for example, say **column R** is **company name** etc. and in your formula you are refering to **column B** that we don't know what it refers to. Your example is lacking clarity. Please clarify better adding column names, english and anything that can allow a community member to understand your problem in one look, rather than spending hours looking at what you are looking for.

Comment: i converted all texts into English as a small sample and also i uploaded it on the following link:  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=53364233111112661814               for example if you choose spain from the combobox you will get company z twice it should be with different value but it just get first raw repeated

Comment: modify formula in S3 to be : =IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$22,$N3,COLUMNS($R$3:R3)),"")  by the way, there is a good Arabic forum for Office : http://www.officena.net/ib/index.php?showforum=135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@houssam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189340/index-match-formula-does-not-show-the-repeated-entrey-with-different-value/30195139#comment48491638_30189340) said, you can try this one in **S3**:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$22,$N3,COLUMNS($R$3:R3)),"")
```

does this help?

Comment: thank you very much, worked perfectly, and i am already a member on officena and its real wonderful forum has so many experts i can tell. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Company Name to match while it is not unique. `MATCH` always returns the first occurrence index it finds.

You can use the same formula you used to find the company name for the other columns, and that will ensure you get the same row data. Just copy the cell from Company Name to the other columns, so the formula in `S3` will be:

```
INDEX($B$3:$K$32,$N3,COLUMNS($R$3:S3)
```

R3 changes to S3, and this will return the Amount column, as `COLUMNS($R$3:S3)` returns 2.